# How to subprocess this CLI command

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to get output of this shell command using Python:

```
loginctl show-session -p Display -p Active c2
```

Output is:

```
Display=:0
Active=yes
```

In Python, I do it this way:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['loginctl', 'show-session -p Display -p Active c2'])
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown operation show-session -p Display -p Active c2
```

What could be cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(['loginctl', 'show-session', '-p', 'Display', '-p', 'Active', 'c2'])
```

Or, if you're comfortable with basic shell splitting:

```
import shlex
cmd = 'loginctl show-session -p Display -p Active c2'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Be wary if sending user input directly to `str.split` or `shlex.split` and using the result with `subprocess`, it's too easy to bypass.

Adding `shell = True` should also work but with quite a few side effects, see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/37020).

Comment: `subprocess.call(cmd.split())` would this also work for some command like `git commit -m "This is a message"`? Note the use of spaces.

Comment: @aceph: don't use `.split()` or `shlex.split()` unless the input is a string literal here—both are easily fooled. `.split()` could be used to make the line less "noisy", to make the command more readable. If the input is not a constant then use a list: *one list item per the command-line argument*

Comment: @aceph - no, in your case it won't, but as @J.F Sebastian mentioned `shlex.split` will. Never trust it with external input, though. Edited the answer, shlex.split is much better than str.split here (TIL)

Answer (score -1):

Try with `shell = True`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('loginctl show-session -p Display -p Active c2', shell= True)
```

Output:

```
Display=:0
Active=yes
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is valid for quick&dirty cases (e.g replacing a shell script) but you should be aware of the implementation and the risks: official docs - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments, SO answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/37020